# How do I run a python 3 script that imports yaml from bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I am calling a python script using python2.x from inside a bash script.  How can I update it to python 3.X?

This is a script I need to be able to distribute to clients, using the venv cli will not work

Running on CentOS

First I've installed any number of python 3 packages.

```
$ sudo yum list installed | grep python3

python3-other-rpm-macros.noarch         3-25.el7                       @epel    
python34.x86_64                         3.4.10-2.el7                   @epel    
python34-devel.x86_64                   3.4.10-2.el7                   @epel    
python34-libs.x86_64                    3.4.10-2.el7                   @epel    
python34-pip.noarch                     8.1.2-8.el7                    @epel    
python34-setuptools.noarch              39.2.0-3.el7                   @epel    
python36.x86_64                         3.6.8-1.el7                    @epel    
python36-libs.x86_64                    3.6.8-1.el7                    @epel
```

```
$ sudo pip3.4 install pyyaml
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyyaml in /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages
```

from bash script do_update.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 update_yaml.py
```

from python script update_yaml.py

```
import sys
import common_update
import subprocess

with open.('input.yaml') as in_yaml:
  input_data = yaml.safe_load(in_yaml)
```

I expect it to parse input.yaml

Output: `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'"`

Comment: You have multiple python3 binaries installed. Check which python binary is aliased to `python3` by running `which python3`

Comment: ```$ which python3

/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3` is a symlink to something. Check what by running `ls -l /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6

Comment: And there's your problem. You installed pyyaml for python3.4 but you are using python3.6 to run the script

Comment: Run the script with `python3.4 update_yaml.py`

Comment: That seems to have done it - python3.4 update_yaml.py works.

Comment: You don't need Bash here at all. Just put a shebang in the Python script itself; `#!/usr/bin/env python3.4`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have multiple versions of python installed.

It's no longer recommended to use the `pip` script (or `pip3.4` etc.)
A common problem is that you actually install packages for a different python version than the one you expected.

Instead do this:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pyyaml
```

This way you can be sure that `python3` will be able to use the library.

Answer (score 0):

Do not *ever* run `pip install` under root in CentOS/RHEL unless it happens inside `virtualenv`, or unless you want to screw your system.

There *is* package:

```
yum install python34-PyYAML
```